# Virtualbox not working on windows 10 (amd)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, 64-bit

I have been having a problem for every single VirtualBox version that I install on my computer. (I have tried all the virtual box version from 6.10 - 6.18) It boots the OS fine, but when it is initializing the kernel or trying to boot, it either hangs or it gets kernel panic errors. I am on windows 10 home and VMware is working properly. I have also installed the virtualbox extension pack. (Yes I have tried a restart) I have created all VM's inside virtualbox and vmware is currently uninstalled.

Examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYV5y.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6SBq.png I have also gotten kernel panic errors, but don't have a screenshot of those right now.

Comment: You mention both VirtualBox and VMWare.  Are you actually using both of those hypervisors?  Additionally, your second screenshot indicates a networking issue, I suspect the VirtualBox virtual networking adapter might not be properly working.  It's unusual to have both VirtualBox and VMWare installed on the same system

Comment: Have you tried to create and set up a VM from scratch?

Comment: yes I have created one from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried virtualbox on another amd laptop and the same thing happened, but I ran `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and it fixed the problem. The only issue is that I can't run wsl with the hypervisorlaunchtype off.

Answer (score 2):

From those logs you seem to be starting a VMWare based VM with VirtualBox. That is a sure way to cause trouble. (It is trying to use the VMWare NIC which isn't there.)

Also having VMWare and VirtualBox installed in parallel on the same host-system is also not a good idea. They may interfere.

The proper way to migrate a VM from one virtualization product to another is to export the VM from the original software as an OVA or OVF archive. Then import that archive into the other virtualization product.
You still may need to adjust some things afterwards. (Like installing the guest-additions.)

And please note that VirtualBox has a VMWare compatible video-emulation. You may have to use that initially to get video working. After you have installed the VirtualBox guest additions you can shutdown the VM, change the video-emulation to VBOXsVGA and then adjust the video-settings inside the VM.

Comment: I created the VM from scratch inside virtual box and I have done it several times. Also I forgot to mention that I have uninstalled VMware, but I think uninstalling it was not enough.

Comment: I reinstalled virtualbox and removed all the vbox drivers from system32, and I removed all traces of virtualbox (except the registry keys). It still dosen't work, I am getting kernel panic in arch linux, and ubuntu freeezes with no errors on startup.